# Cakephp 3.0 router.php not working

Tags: php, routes, cakephp-3.2

I got the following code on my router.php file:

```
<?php

use Cake\Routing\Router;

 Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
$routes->redirect('/e/*', 'http://google.com', ['status' => 302]);
});

?>
```

Though, when I go to https://mywebsite.domain.domain/e/testing it gives the following message:

[image: Error message]

Any sugestion?

Edit: I'm using Php 7.0. Tested on php 5.6.10 and worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a error in cake version. Updated and worked fine